# io_remap_pfn_range issue on powerpc

Tags: linux-kernel, powerpc

I'd like to access to PCIe IO from userland.

In the module driver, I'm able to write/read using the pointer returned by ioremap () without any problem.

From userland, I want to use the pointer returned by mmap () but the host hangs whatever I write or read on the PCIe bus.
I implemented the mmap call in the file operation structure which calls `io_remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, start >> PAGE_SHIFT, vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start, vma->vm_page_prot);` where start is the value returned by pci_resource_start ().

What did I miss ?

Note that my module works fine on x86.

Thanks,

Fred

Comment: Are you trying to access PCIe *IO* space, or PCIe memory space?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to access PCIe IO space.

Answer (score 1):

The POWER architecture does not support PCIe IO accesses; you'll need to use PCIe memory cycles instead. It's likely that your PCIe device has a corresponding resource for MMIO space, perhaps you can use that.

Also, depending on your usage, you may want to perform accesses on the `resource<N>` files in sysfs, under `/sys/bus/pci/devices/<id>`. This might mean that you don't need any kernel code at all.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've implemented read/write methods so I can perform I/O accesses from the device. It's not too bad.